# Data Error 26 with DataTemplate and ItemTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate

I have a TabControl with a single specific tab and a collection bound to a collection of VMs, using a different user control. To do this I use a CompositeCollection and DataTemplates defined in the control's resources, selecting correct user control based on the VM type (acting as ContentTemplate).

I also set an ItemTemplate to define the tab item's name with binding, but it's not defined in the resource as I guess would conflict with the "ContentTemplate" ones.

It works fine, but I see the following error traced:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 26 : ItemTemplate and ItemTemplateSelector are ignored for items already of the ItemsControl's container type; Type='TabItem'

It looks like there's some conflict between ContentTemplate and ItemTemplate, but I don't know how to fix it?

Code is the following:

```
<TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="300" Width="500">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="personCollection" Source="{Binding Persons}" />
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:Main}">
            <local:MainView />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:Person}">
            <local:PersonView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.Resources>
    <TabControl.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <TabItem Header="General" Content="{Binding }"/>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource personCollection}}" />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </TabControl.ItemsSource>
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="viewModel:Person">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error you observe is pretty obvious.
You define the `ItemsSource` of your `TabControl` as a `CompositeCollection` that contains elements of different types:

- a `TabItem` "General";
- a bunch of `Person` viewmodels.

So you're just mixing in one collection a view and some viewmodels - that's not neat. WPF informs you about this with the error message. The engine tries to create views (using `DataTemplate`s) for the items and suddenly encounters an already specified view (a `TabItem`) that is exactly of type of the item container (because for the `TabControl`, a view for each viewmodel will be inserted in a `TabItem` container). So WPF simply inserts the `TabItem` into the `TabControl` and notifies that it has not used any `ItemTemplate` or `ItemTemplateSelector` for creating it.

You could simply ignore this error, because in the end the control should look like you want it to (I suppose).

An alternative (and probably neater) way is not to mix views and viewmodels in one collection, but rather specify a "general" viewmodel for the "General" tab:

```
<TabControl.ItemsSource>
    <CompositeCollection>
        <viewModel:GeneralViewModel/>
        <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource personCollection}}" />
    </CompositeCollection>
</TabControl.ItemsSource>
```

And of course you then need to tell WPF how to visualize it:

```
<TabControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:GeneralViewModel}">
        <local:GeneralView />
    </DataTemplate>
    <!-- ... -->
</TabControl.Resources>
```

---

### Update

To address the issues in your comments.

1.
*How do I bind the GeneralViewModel to the one that exist in my DataContext?*
This is possible, but with some overhead. You have to create a binding proxy for this. (Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28179316/2846483).)
The second thing you will need is a markup extension:

```
class BindingProxyValue : MarkupExtension
{
    public BindingProxy Proxy { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return Proxy.DataContext;
    }   
}
```

Use this markup extension together with the binding proxy in your collection:

```
<TabControl.Resources>
    <local:BindingProxy x:Key="Proxy" DataContext="{Binding GeneralViewModel}"/>
</TabControl.Resources>
<!--...-->
<CompositeCollection>
   <local:BindingProxyValue Proxy="{StaticResource Proxy}"/>
   <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource personCollection}}" />
</CompositeCollection>
```

You can extend the markup extension as you like, e.g. in such a way that it can observe the object updates and replace the item in the target `CompositeCollection`.

2.
*How do I specify general tab's header name?*
You can use `ItemTemplate`s, but it becomes a little bit complicated. You have to implement a `DataTemplateSelector` for your `TabControl`:

```
class YourTabItemDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;

        if (element != null && item != null)
        {
            if (item is GeneralViewmodel)
            {
                return (DataTemplate)element.FindResource("GeneralTabItemTemplate");
            }
            else
            {
                return (DataTemplate)element.FindResource("PersonTabItemTemplate");
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Then you can define the different `ItemTemplate`s for different `TabItem`s:

```
<TabControl.Resources>
    <!-- ... -->
    <DataTemplate x:Key="GeneralTabItemTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="General" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PersonTabItemTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</TabControl.Resources>
```

**The question is: is this effort worth it or are you okay with that error message 26? You decide.**

Comment: Nice answer, thanks! However I have two problems with this solution: 1. how do I bind the GeneralViewModel to the one that exist in my DataContext (I don't want to create another one, and it has no default ctor) 2. How do I specify general tab's header name (as I can't set ItemTemplate for it)?

Comment: Valid solution, but having tried these techniques and not been impressed with 1) the verbosity and 2) the fact that you have to pollute your code-behind with dummy viewmodels, I've just decided to ignore Error 26 and go about my business.