# TabItem binding content dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Trying to build a TabControl dynamically, but it won't bind the UserControl I've created.  I've extended TabItem to add some close functionality to the header.

The error it gives is:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 26 : ItemTemplate and ItemTemplateSelector are ignored for items already of the ItemsControl's container type; Type='ClosableTab'
```

I end up with System.Windows.Controls.Grid in plain text rather than a control.  The UserControl is just containing a TextBlock in an empty grid for testing purposes.

The error is remarkably similar to this question: [Data Error 26 with DataTemplate and ItemTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44457888/data-error-26-with-datatemplate-and-itemtemplate#) but my code is different and I can't figure out if it's the same, but I have tried to search.

And this code contains is sourced from multiple tutorials, I'm still only a month in so sorry if I've missed something obvious.

```
<TabControl TabStripPlacement="Top"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Titles, Mode=TwoWay}"
            Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

The extended TabItem class.  TabHeader is just Xaml to add a close button to the header, works fine.
{Binding Content} does show a warning,

```
Cannot resolve property 'Content' in data context of type MyApp.ViewModel.MainWindowViewModel
```

Perhaps this is key?

```
public class ClosableTab : TabItem
{
    public ClosableTab(string headerText, UserControl content)
    {
        TabHeader header = new TabHeader();
        Header = header;
        Title = headerText;
        Content = content;
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get { return Title.ToString(); }
        set
        {
            ((TabHeader)this.Header).label_TabTitle.Content = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The ICommand event handler

```
private ObservableCollection<ClosableTab> _titles; 

public ObservableCollection<ClosableTab> Titles
{
    get { return _titles; }
    set
    {
        _titles = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Titles");
    }
}

private void AddTabItem(string title)
{
    ClosableTab Item;
    Item = new ClosableTab("Setup", new Setup());
    Titles.Add(Item);
    Item.Focus();
    OnPropertyChanged("Titles");
}
```

New Setup() is a user control containing just a Grid and a TextBlock.

Everything works perfectly, the header is built with the title and close button, but the content just returns text, System.Windows.Controls.Grid?

Answer (score 0):

```
<TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</TabControl.ContentTemplate>
```

TextBlock... I am not a smart man.